# Getting AccessTokenRefreshError 'invalid_grant' on dev_appserver when using cloudstorage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-storage

When trying out the [Google Cloud Storage sample](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample) (or any call to write files using the `cloudstorage` module, in other projects as well) I am getting a the following error

```
INFO     2016-12-05 01:16:06,999 client.py:804] Refreshing access_token
INFO     2016-12-05 01:16:07,198 client.py:827] Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
ERROR    2016-12-05 01:16:07,200 api_server.py:272] Exception while handling service_name: "app_identity_service"
method: "GetAccessToken"
request: "\n7https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"
request_id: "YpfXhQJczA"

... long long stack traces ...

RuntimeError: AccessTokenRefreshError(u'invalid_grant',)
```

Trouble is, when I deploy the app to Google App Engine, the call works just fine.

Comment: Try export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=PATH/FILE.json . See more: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I spent a few hours searching and debugging the client code till I found out that the `oauth2client` was using some [default application credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) stored somewhere in the file system. It seems that these credentials, which were probably left over from a previous version of the GAE SDK included an old refresh token that got rejected by Google.

On windows those credentials were stored in

```
C:\Users\$USER\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json
```

The easy way to recreate these credentials is with the `gcloud` tool:

```
$ gcloud auth application-default login
```

(Note that `gcloud auth login` only sets up credentials for working with the `gcloud` utility itself, not for your app calling Google client libraries, so is not what is needed here).

Hope this can save someone else a few hours.

Comment: I can confirm this saved me a few hours.